# Can I obtain real money with Black Squad boxes?

Tags: steam, steam-community-market, black-squad

I know about Counter Strike, and I don't know if Black Squad has the same system (drop random items with real money value in boxes). I took a look at the forums and it looks like this game has this system but I don't see the cost of each item that can be dropped in the box.

I want to earn real money on Steam without actually putting any money of my real money.

Comment: can you please post which forums you took a look at? It would help us to know what did you searched already...

Comment: https://steamcommunity.com/app/550650/discussions/0/1474221865183576740/

Comment: If you look at the steam market place you can't find any black squad items on sale except wallpapers and emoticons. So no I don't think you'll be able to sell stuff for real money.

Comment: yes i saw that, but dont know so i answer here, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community market will be opened soon(™). April 2018 has been mentioned, but there is no official date yet.

According to [this article](http://blacksquad.com/2018/04/06/early-access-patch-note-11-big-update-2-2-4-2-2-2-2/) a large number of weapons will become tradable. It also includes a list of what weapons which you'll be able to trade.

Once that happened you'll be able to see the prices as you already know it from CS:GO.

Comment: ty dly, so free money for steam in a free game :)

Comment: @dherediat I presume you'd need to play the game to get the stuff to then sell it.  Boosting the number of active players at any given time is not nothing to a company who makes games like this, so you *are* providing them a service for the money you earn this way.

Comment: @Steve-O yes, is the main purpose of this game(obtain more active players)